# When adding new data/rows to a one jqGrid1 from another jqGrid2, the old data in jqGrid1 is lost (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have jqGrid parent and another jqGrid child in a popup dialoag. The parent jqGrid has already a set of records in it and whenever I add new set of records from child jqGrid to parent jqGrid, I am losing the existing data from the parent jqGrid.

I tried the following.

1. concat the data from the parent to the child and then set it to the parent jqGrid.

   ```js
   var gridParent = jQuery("#parentGrid");
   var existingRowsInParentGrid = gridParent.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');

   var gridChild = jQuery("#childGrid");
   var newRowsInChildGrid = gridChild .jqGrid('getGridParam','data');

   var json = existingRowsInParentGrid.concat(newRowsInChildGrid );

   //set the new concatnated data to parent
   gridParent.jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: json}).trigger('reloadGrid');
   ```
2. Tried to use

   ```js
   Object.assign(existingRowsInParentGrid, newRowsInChildGrid)
   ```
3. Tried to use the extend feature.

   ```js
   var sum = jQuery.extend(existingRowsInParentGrid, newRowsInChildGrid );
   ```

It simply replaces the existing records with the new set of records. I am not adding records one at a time but setting the data in bulk. Does this make the difference?

I see lots of code, which tells me to add one record at a time. I was hoping that there will one way where we just need to add the whole set of new records at the end of the existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not post the configuration of both grids it is difficult to help.

In most cases it is better to read the up to date documentation, rather than to read some posts. If you do not know addRowData can add multiple rows at once.

For more info refer the docs [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/) (search for addRowData method)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Tony.
I've found the solution after doing trial and error. Below is what I did which worked for me, perhaps it might help someone else!

1. Find the number of rows from the first jqGrid.

var existingRowsInParentGrid = gridParent.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
var noOfRowsInParentGrid = existingRowsInParentGrid.length;

2. Find the number of rows from the second jqGrid.

var noOfRowsInChildGrid = gridChild.length;

3. Iterate through the 2nd grid elements and add rows to the parent grid at the correct position.

   for(var i = 0;i < noOfRowsInChildGrid; i++) {
   gridParent.jqGrid('addRowData', noOfRowsInParentGrid +1 , gridChild[i]);
   noOfRowsInParentGrid = noOfRowsInParentGrid + 1;
   }

My initial intention of loading the data in bulk still did not work though. But for now, I am happy as I will not have a huge amount of data in 2nd grid.